# The process cannot access the file 'XXX' because it is being used by another process, if i send a second time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, docusignapi, filestream

I have this error when when I reload my page in Dev mode to create a second mail and send it with a file, it falls in the 1st variable "emc"even if it is the 2nd variable "eqc" which is "true" and in prod is still going on this error as if the file was still open, I do not know where, I know I have to close the "path", but can you tell me where? This is my code:

```
public ActionResult EditPersonalityTest([Bind(Include = "ID,EnglishProefficiencyBefore")] Recipient recipient, CohortSubscriptions cohortSubscriptions)
        {

            var property = db.CohortSubscriptions.Where(x => x.ID == cohortSubscriptions.ID).FirstOrDefault();

            property.EnglishProefficiencyBefore = cohortSubscriptions.EnglishProefficiencyBefore;


            db.Entry(property).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            Registrations registration = db.Registrations.Where(x => x.ID == property.RegistrationId).FirstOrDefault();
            bool isEnglish = IsEnglishLocale(registration);
            recipient.Name = registration.FirstName + " " + registration.LastName;
            recipient.Email = registration.Email;

            Recipient recipientModel = new Recipient();
            string directorypath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + "Files/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(directorypath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directorypath);
            }
            byte[] data;

            bool englishMontreal = isEnglish  && registration.PreferredCampus == "Montreal";
            bool englishQuebec = isEnglish  && registration.PreferredCampus == "Québec";
            bool frenchMontreal = isEnglish == false && registration.PreferredCampus == "Montreal";
            bool frenchQuebec = isEnglish == false && registration.PreferredCampus == "Québec";

            //English Montreal First Contract
            var emc = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Contrats Montreal English.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
            //English Quebec First Contract
            var eqc = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Contrats Quebec English.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
            //English Secon Contract
            //var esc = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/CodeBoxx Technology Corporation English.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
            //French Montreal First Contract
            var fmc = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Contrats Montreal French.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
            //French Quebec First Contract
            var fqc = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Contrats Quebec French.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
            //French Second Contract
            //var fsc = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/CodeBoxx Technology Corporation Contrat.pdf"), FileMode.Open);


            if (englishMontreal == true)
            {


                //First contract
                using (Stream inputStream = emc)
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                    if (memoryStream == null)
                    {
                        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                serverpath = directorypath + recipient.Name.Trim() + ".pdf";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(serverpath, data);
                docusignContract(serverpath, recipient.Name, recipient.Email);
            }

            if (englishQuebec == true)
            {


                using (Stream inputStream = eqc)
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                    if (memoryStream == null)
                    {
                        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                serverpath = directorypath + recipient.Name.Trim() + ".pdf";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(serverpath, data);
                docusignContract(serverpath, recipient.Name, recipient.Email);


            }

            if (frenchMontreal == true)
            {
                using (Stream inputStream = fmc)
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                    if (memoryStream == null)
                    {
                        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                serverpath = directorypath + recipient.Name.Trim() + ".pdf";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(serverpath, data);
                docusignContract(serverpath, recipient.Name, recipient.Email);


            }

            if (frenchQuebec == true)
            {
                using (Stream inputStream = fqc)
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                    if (memoryStream == null)
                    {
                        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                serverpath = directorypath + recipient.Name.Trim() + ".pdf";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(serverpath, data);
                docusignContract(serverpath, recipient.Name, recipient.Email);

            }
            System.IO.File.Delete(serverpath);  //my supposition
            return View("ConfirmEditSubscriptions");

        }
```

Comment: All of your `using` statements are inside `if` statements, which means that the `using` block is being set up *conditionally.*  Which means there are conditions under which some files will never get closed.

Comment: Try something like this instead: `using (Stream inputStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Contrats Montreal English.pdf"), FileMode.Open) { }`  Or, put your initial stream variable declarations inside the appropriate if blocks, so that they go out of scope when you leave the if blocks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey your answer solved part of my problem, in Dev I can send several emails away with the document, but in production I have the same problem, can you tell me how to close the file please, with my code

Comment: The `using` statement closes the file when execution leaves the `using` block.  But the `using` statement does you no good if it never executes.

Comment: And the change I suggested has to be done with *all* of your variables, not just the first one.

Comment: Also, *did you deploy your code changes to production?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes I did and yes it is deployed in production. Do you know why the using statement nevers executes...? btw thanks for the help I really appreciate it

Comment: It doesn't always execute because it's inside of an `if` statement.  Consider the case where your `if` condition evaluates to `false`.

Comment: yes indeed but when I debug in enteres in the right if... but it stills saying the same error in prod but working perfectly in dev...

Comment: @Frankthetank, any chance to look at the Answer, I think it covers it

Answer (score 0):

You might have already found the issue by now but here is what I've found.

There are several *FileStream open* that are *never used*. Streams `emc`,`eqc`,`fmc`,`fqc` are open at each time the function is called, *only 1* is being **Disposed**, that's why on the second call some file are still `being used by another process`

To make this easier to debug, I always start to remove **code duplication**, Basically your function is having 4 times the *same code block* identical at 99% except the `inputStream` source.

From your code, I've also noticed that this code block will **always return a `null inputStream`**

```cs
...
using (Stream inputStream = eqc) {
MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream; //eqc is a FileStream, it is not castable as MemoryStream, This is always null
...
```

**Solution**

Here is a *small refactor* of your function. I removed `unused variables` and I've moved variable definition closer to the usage. You will also notice that there is no `if ()` statement remaining (`Directory.CreateDirectory()` will not throw an exception if directory already exist). 
**My rule for better code** : Remove as many [if] as possible, it will reduce code paths and chances of errors.

```cs
public ActionResult EditPersonalityTest([Bind(Include = "ID,EnglishProefficiencyBefore")] Recipient recipient, CohortSubscriptions cohortSubscriptions)
{
    var property = db.CohortSubscriptions.Where(x => x.ID == cohortSubscriptions.ID).FirstOrDefault();

    property.EnglishProefficiencyBefore = cohortSubscriptions.EnglishProefficiencyBefore;

    db.Entry(property).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    Registrations registration = db.Registrations.Where(x => x.ID == property.RegistrationId).FirstOrDefault();
    recipient.Name = registration.FirstName + " " + registration.LastName;
    recipient.Email = registration.Email;

    //Array to map campus name to FileNamePart
    var campusNameMap = new[] {
        new { PreferredCampus = "Montreal", FileNamePart = "Montreal" },
        new { PreferredCampus = "Québec", FileNamePart = "Quebec" },
    };

    //Generate pdfDocumentPath based on isEnglish and registration.PreferredCampus
    string campusFileNamePart = campusNameMap.Single(campus => campus.PreferredCampus == registration.PreferredCampus).FileNamePart;
    string languageFileNamePart = IsEnglishLocale(registration) ? "English" : "French";

    //Use only 1 inputStream
    using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath($"~/Documents/Contrats {campusFileNamePart} {languageFileNamePart}.pdf"), FileMode.Open))
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

        string directorypath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files/");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directorypath);

        string serverpath = $"{directorypath}{recipient.Name.Trim()}.pdf";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(serverpath, memoryStream.ToArray());

        docusignContract(serverpath, recipient.Name, recipient.Email);

        System.IO.File.Delete(serverpath);
    }

    return View("ConfirmEditSubscriptions");
}
```

I hope it will work for you.